# Regex: Match all, but ignore a specific word

Tags: regex

**Sample 1 String:**

```
Aquaman Figure, XL DC Comics
```

**Sample 2 String:**

```
Rocket Raccoon, Mini Marvel
```

**Regex:**

```
/(DC Comics|Marvel)/
```

**Match Sample 1:**

```
DC Comics
```

**Match Sample 2:**

```
Marvel
```

Works perfectly in [Regex101](http://regex101.com/)

How do I reverse this?

I want to match `Aquaman Figure, XL` and `Rocket Raccoon, Mini` only.

**Edit:** 
`/(.+)(?=Marvel)/` seems to do the job. It excludes Marvel from Rocket Raccon! How do I make this also work with DC comics?

Comment: Why don't you just replace Marvel and DC Comics by empty string?

Comment: (.+)(?=Marvel|DC Comics). The problem is with expressions like "Marvel Aquaman Figure, XL" it won't work replacement seems would be the best choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/(.+)(?=Marvel)/` (or `/(.+)(?=DC Comics|Marvel)/` for both) isn't going to work for something like:

```
John Marvel Bob
```

For which I presume you want the result to be:

```
John  Bob
```

You'll only get `John` in the first match, and you'll get `Marvel Bob` in the second match (since look-ahead doesn't consume the looked-ahead characters).

Or something that doesn't contain either of the strings (since you require that the next characters match some given characters to get a match).

---

The easiest solution is probably just replacing the two desired sub-strings with empty strings. Replace:

```
DC Comics|Marvel
```

with:

```
(empty string)
```

---

Or you can repeatedly search for:

```
/(.*?)(DC Comics|Marvel|$)/
```

And just extract the first [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (which will correspond to what matches `.*`, which is everything starting from the end of the last match up to just before "DC Comics", "Marvel" or the end of the string).

The [reluctant quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `?` is needed to prevent the `.*` from matching `John Marvel Bob`, rather than just `John` in `John Marvel Bob Marvel`.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r"(.*)(?=Marvel|Comics)",input)
```

This does exactly what you are looking for.Its in python.input will be your string.